# Which threat level is Garou?

Tags: one-punch-man

AFAIK , season 2 of *One Punch Man* is going to have Garou as the main villain. Which threat level is Garou according to the manga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Chapter 85**, Garou was declared as a Dragon-level threat.

Comment: He declares himself to be a God-level threat at one point, though the association itself never formally assigns that to him. It's certainly his goal to be a God-level threat.

Comment: What was stated it's there, but there is an image in the webcomic which could be Garou, which is labeled "God level threat". I'm going to ask more about it, since I'm not 100% sure if it's him

Comment: @Pablo He self-proclaimed himself as a God-level threat. It is in Chapter 77 & 83 of the webcomic. The association never declared it officially, though.